# Android - How can I know model of connected android wear device?

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it `moto 360`, `lg g watch` or other...
How can I get this information in the code in independent android app?

Possible it's duplicate, but I didn't find anything in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
String watchModel = Build.MODEL;
```

on the watch itself and sent this to the phone.

This requires making a android wear activity and starting it on the watch in the background from the phone

Comment: Thank you, If I don't find a better solution I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ adb shell getprop ro.product.model
```

output:

```
SOME_MODEL_NAME_SET_BY_PRODUCER
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but actually I asked how do it in the code.